# event for show/hide list with options of < select > element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, select, dropdown

All!!!

What events should be used when showing or hiding the dropdown list of < option >'s of < select > element?

Actions:

1. The user press key (Enter for example) or clicked the cursor on an < select > item and was showed dropdown list of < option >'s
2. The user press key (Esc for example) or select other html element and was hidded dropdown list of < option >'s

   item #1
        item #1
        item #1

   $('#myselect').on('event_show_dropdrown_list', function(){});
   $('#myselect').on('event_hide_dropdrown_list', function(){});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`focusin()` and `focusout()` jquery methods should do what you are looking for

https://api.jquery.com/focusin/

Comment: no, no, no :(  
  
 First click on select element - **focusin success**.  
  
 Second click on select element (focus was not changed) - **focusin<br/> fail**.  
  
  
 I want to register an event in the drop-down list, rather than the change in focus (this is not exactly what I need)

Comment: Sorry @Zhihar I am completely lost now.. you might want to consider rewriting your question. Im really struggling to make sense of what you are after.

Comment: Sorry @Ash

I want to determine when an element < select > is folded a drop-down list, and when it is folded. I have not found the right event for the < select > item.

I created the following code (but it is very long and uncomfortable):
https://jsfiddle.net/tf704ycw/

Comment: What do you mean by folded a drop down list?

Comment: sorry for my english

element SELECT - dropdown list

`<form>`
`<select>`
`<option>#1</option>`
`<option>#2</option>`
`<option>#3</option>`
`</select>`
`</form>`

for example - https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC725266.png

dropdown list = EDIT + DROPDOWN

initially DROPDOWN is hidden (folded),
when the user clicks on an SELECT element with the mouse or presses a key on the keyboard DROPDOWN component of SELECT element is visible (unfolds).

DROPDOWN component events are not known to me

Comment: there are no dedicated events for dropdown components, however you could use the onchange event (jquery .change() method) or why not just add a simple click event to the option so it fires when clicked? If unfolded when clicked then you can assume this is now "unfolded" if unfolded when clicked you can assume its now "folded"